# Where can I read more about D's class access modifiers?

Tags: d, access-modifiers

I can't seem to find a good reference for the [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29) programming language class access modifiers.

I know that `public` and `private` are pretty much guaranteed but i'm guessing there are more, i just can't seem to find a good source of information.

Can anyone point me to a good reference please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check the official reference at [dlang.org](http://dlang.org/spec/attribute.html#ProtectionAttribute)

in short:

- `private`, is only accessible in the same module (file)
- `package`, is only accessible in the same package
- `protected`, is module + inherited classes
- `public` (also the default) is accessible every where
- `export` is use to export functions when you are writing libraries

Comment: Thanks! Why on earth didn't they put this info on the class page?

Comment: @Gary, because D is not an object-oriented only language, they have meaning outside a class except protected.

Comment: I think they can be used at the module level as well.

Comment: Yes, functions or any variable can be prefixed by any of the above except protected. Especially export is used often on module level, but occasionally I use private as well. In this case the module simulates a class with just member functions and no variables. Note how private differs in definition from most languages.